# How to get notfications of ppa updates?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, notification

How can I get notified of updates to a certain PPA?

For example when I am interested in new package versions of a certain package in a certain PPA?

If a user has the package in question installed and is using the default desktop, she probably get notified via an icon in the traybar or something like that.

But I am searching for a method which works even when the package is not installed (and without gnome).

It should be reliable and prompt.

Does launchpad provides some RSS/Atom-Feed features for PPAs? Or email notifications?

(As a sidenote: I am surprised that even with my own PPA I only get an upload notification via mail - but no notification when the binary package is finished.)

Comment: Just my 2 cents: perhaps create a script with wget and time-stamping in order to check for changes? More info at: http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html

Comment: Hm, perhaps - the Link to the official manual location is: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping

Comment: Re: your sidenote: You might want to look at this old launchpad-user thread: https://lists.launchpad.net/launchpad-users/msg05540.html Especially the code here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/298022/ The API has changed a bit since then, but it should be possible to hack something up to check build status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, Launchpad doesn't offer RSS feeds for PPAs. There's been an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/207333) on this for a while.

UbuntuUpdates.org is a third party service that offers feeds for some [selected PPAs](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas).